Height and intersection
Let $X$ be a surface. Let $C \subset X$ be a curve on $X$ and $P$ an algebraic point on that curve. Take an effective divisor $D$ on $X$, one can define the height of $P$ w.r.t. $D$, $h_D(P)$. Now if $C$ does not intersect $D$, a claim says $h_D(P)=O(1)$.
I am confused since the height is only about $P$, one can choose another curve which also contains $P$ and does intersect with $D$, then we should obtain a nontrivial height. Well I also tried to think of that in the persepective of arithmetic intersections, namely, consider
$$h_D(P)=\frac{\hat{\deg}(\mathcal{D}|_{H_P})}{[k(P):k]},$$
where $\hat{\deg}$ is the arithmetic degree, $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{D})$ is a model of $(X,D)$ and $H_P$ is the Zariski closure of the image of $Spec\ \bar{k} \to X \to \mathcal{X}$. Follow that, I believe $H_P$ is not the same thing as $C$ (since $C$ is in the generic fiber), so it does not make sense to me talking about the intersection of $C$ with $D$ to determine the height.
Anything is appreciated, thank you!

maybe it just the basic functoriality of height.

It does not make sense to talk about $O(1)$ when focusing on a single point $P$. If one consider an infinite sequence of $P$ which lie on a curve $C$, it is Zariski closed for dimension reason. So it is unlikely to find another curve also containing those points and with different intersection numbers.
